# Using Laravel 5 with XAMPP database

Tags: laravel

I am watching a tutorial where they are using Homestead but I am using XAMPP and I have installed Laravel 5 on my IDE and I executed the following statement in the command line `php artisan make:migration create_users_table`. 
It created the file inside my project and I have entered the columns I want to create and input what I think to be correct details in the .env file but how do I now create these columns and view them in phpMyAdmin on my localhost. At the moment when I execute `php artisan migrate` in the command line it says `Access denied for user 'myuser@localhost' (using password: YES)`

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        //creates increment field called ID
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        //can be left blank
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('location')->nullable();
        $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    //
}
```

Comment: What have you set up for your database connection in your `.env` file?

Comment: I currently have @James 'DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=social
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=123456'

Comment: @James would I be right in thinking that I do not have to manually create the database and running the command will create the database and the table?

Comment: You **do** need to create the database for Laravel's Schema Builder to be able to create tables within it. However, from the error you posted, the problem seems to be related to having a lack of access to the database in the first place. You need to create the database and allow `myuser` have access to that database for the migrations to work. Also it would be helpful if you would post the migration code as part of your question.

Comment: I would create the database that you need, and as @Bogdan mentioned - ensure that your user `myuser` has the correct privileges to access that database.

Comment: @James thanks it works now I created the database manually

Comment: @Bogdan I have now included my migration code excluding the down function

Comment: @Joey93 glad to hear that. I have added an answer for this for anyone else who has a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap this question up and give it answer, and also for anyone else who stumbles across this question - OP was having trouble here as they hadn't set up their database yet and were relying on their migration to create this.

This isn't quite right and so after setting up the database and ensuring the user had the correct privileges for the database, the migration ran successfully.